# Declaring array variable in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

What is the difference in declaring array variable as of these three styles:

```
Dim MyArr1 As Variant
Dim MyArr2() As Variant
Dim MyArr3()
```

Are all these three dynamic variables?

I cannot find a link to documentation where those three are compared.

**Update.**
I really cannot see a difference when these two codes are executed:

code 1

```
Dim MyArr
MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value
```

code 2

```
Dim MyArr() As Variant
MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value
```

Does it really matter if we declare array in any of the three ways listed above, as long as we want to assign values to array reading them from a range?

```
MyArr=Range("A1:C10").Value
```

Is it so that when the line above is being executed then declaring variable happens just before filling it with values. Just as if we had a hidden line of code:

```
Dim MyArr(10,3) As Variant '10 rows, and 3 columns
```

So does `MyArr` become a static array variable when we read data to it from a range?

Comment: you can also do `MyArr4 = array()` without `Dim` if you're not using `Option Explicit`

Comment: @reportgunner ehhm we should *not* recommend to switch off `Option Explicit` we actually should recommend to always turn it *on*.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I am of the opposing opinion, but I was by no means recommending to turn it off.

Comment: A typed array as 4th "style": Dim MyArr2() As Double

Comment: The difference is that `Dim MyArr()` is definitly an array, and you cannot assign a value to it `MyArr = 5` will fail. But `Dim MyArr` is completely undefined and can either assigned a value `MyArr = 5` will work or an array `MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value` or a range `Set MyArr = Range("a1:c10")`. So be as specific als possible if you declare a variable. That means if you want to do `MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value` then always make sure it is declared as array `Dim MyArr() As Variant` which is the most specific option here. So no one can put something else than an array into it.

Comment: @PEH Your comment is accepted answer to my question.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin posted it as an anwser, so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between …

- `Dim MyArr()` or
  `Dim MyArr() As Variant` (which are the same) and
- `Dim MyArr` or
  `Dim MyArr As Variant` (which are also the same)

… is that `Dim MyArr()` is **definitly** an array, and you cannot assign a value to it: `MyArr = 5` will fail.
While `Dim MyArr` is completely undefined and can either assigned …

- a value `MyArr = 5` (will work)
- or an array `MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value`
- or a range `Set MyArr = Range("a1:c10")`

So be as specific als possible if you declare a variable. That means if you want to do

```
MyArr = Range("a1:c10").Value
```

then always make sure it is declared as array `Dim MyArr() As Variant` which is the most specific option here. So no one can put something else than an array into it. The more specific you are the more save is your code.

Also every coder sees that in a variable `Dim MyVar()` should be an array while in `Dim MyVar` they don't know what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

`Dim MyArr1 As Variant` - MyArr1 is variable with variant type
Variant type can hold any data type or object

Below two are one and same. Its dynamic array whose size is not know at design time.

```
Dim MyArr2() As Variant
Dim MyArr3()
```

---

```
Sub ArayTest()

    Dim MyArr1 As Variant
    Dim MyArr2() As Variant
    Dim MyArr3()

    MyArr1 = 10
    MyArr1 = #1/30/2019#

    '--> You cannot directly assign value to array
    'MyArr2 = 20
    'MyArr3 = 30

    '--> Use Redim to set the size of array

    ReDim MyArr2(1)
    MyArr2(0) = "abc"
    MyArr2(1) = 1324

    '--> variant can hold object
    MyArr1 = Array(1, "s", #1/30/2019#)
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that MyArr1 is not an array? I can fill it with `MyArr1=[NamedRange].Value` And NamedRange can consist of any rectangular size of cells, say A1:B10.

Comment: `MyArr1` is a variable with variant data type

Comment: Is it an **array** variable or not?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin `MyArr1` is `Variant` that means it can be **anything**, depending what you put into it. If you put in a string `MyArr1 = "ABC"` then it is a `Variant/String`. If you put in an array `MyArr1 = Array("a", "b", "c")` then it is a `Variant/Array`. You cannot tell just by its declaration.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin variant by definition can accept any type. if you assign an array or a result of a function that returns an array to MyArr1 it will be an array.

Answer (score 2):

`Variant` can be anything, as we can read in [Variant data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type):

> The Variant data type is the data type for all variables that are not explicitly declared as some other type (using statements such as Dim, Private, Public, or Static).
>
> The Variant data type has no type-declaration character.
>
> You can use the Variant data type in place of any data type

This basically means that `Dim MyArr1 As Variant` implies that `MyArr1` can also be array of variants.

But last two means that you are declaring `Array` of "anythings", but only the first can be anything :)

Comment: Can you please explain your sentence `But last two means that you are declaring Array of "anythings", but only the first can be anything :)`? It sound philosophical:-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Think of `Variant` as "anything", even as array of `Variant` or any other datatype. But last two are arrays of variants, so they cannot be `Integer` etc., but they can be array of `Integer`, they can be array of anythings, but they cannot be anything (thay are arrays).