# What is the difference of Array("2023","2024","2025") and Array("2023,2024,2025") and Array(2023, 2024, 2025) in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this in my code:

```
Dim cYear() As Variant
```

I am not so sure what to code next. Should it be like this:

```
cYear = Array("2023","2024","2025")
```

or

```
cYear = Array("2023,2024,2025")
```

or

```
cYear = Array(2023, 2024, 2025)
```

Please advise. Thank you..

Comment: The first is an array of three strings. The second is an array of one string. The third is an array of three numbers.

Comment: Worth reading as additional information: [declaring array variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437183/declaring-array-variable-in-vba/54440292#54440292) and [Assigning to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908721/assigning-to-arrays/72908903#72908903)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Array("2023","2024","2025")
```

is an array of three strings.

```
Array("2023,2024,2025")
```

is an array of one string.

```
Array(2023, 2024, 2025)
```

is an array of three integers.

Comment: To be pedantic, when an array is created using Array(xxx) the result is an array of variants.  Thus the first example above is an array of three Variants containing strings.  The difference between Dim cYear() as string and Dim cYear() as variant is that in the former case cYear=Array("2023","2024","2025") will give a runtime error (Type mismatch) as you can't assign a variant to a string.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel VBA, arrays are a way to store multiple values in a single variable. However, there are differences between the three array declarations you mentioned.

This is an array of strings.

```
Array("2023","2024","2025")
```

The array has three elements: `"2023", "2024", and "2025"`. The elements are stored as text, even though they look like numbers.

Next

```
Array("2023,2024,2025")
```

This is also an array of strings, but it only has one element:
`"2023,2024,2025".`
The entire string is considered one element.

Next

```
Array(2023, 2024, 2025)
```

This is an array of integers `(Long data type in VBA)`. The array has three elements: `2023, 2024, and 2025`. The elements are stored as numbers.

When using arrays in VBA, it's important to declare them with the correct data type and consider how the elements will be stored. In your specific case, if you need an array of numbers, you should use:

```
Array(2023, 2024, 2025)
```

If you need an array of strings, you should use:

```
Array("2023", "2024", "2025")
```

or

```
Array("2023,2024,2025")
```

depending on your requirements.